# subtraction of all permutations in a matrix

Tags: r

I apologise for the very basic question, but after hours of searching i haven't found an answer yet. I have a matrix with 5 repeats (1:5) of a variable (cADP)

```
cADP2
      [,1]
[1,] -3.932778
[2,] -3.807778
[3,] -3.515652
[4,] -2.853333
[5,] -2.054667
```

I would like to compute a subtraction between all permutations of each variable, i.e. 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, 3-4, 3-5, 4-5
but cannot figure out the code required. Many thanks for any assistance offered.

Comment: You should show us what you've tried so far and how it deviates from what you need. We're not a code-writing service, we're a remover of blockers.

Comment: apologies, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `outer` with "-" as the function:

```
cADP2 <- c(-3.932778,-3.807778,-3.515652,-2.853333,-2.054667)
outer(cADP2,cADP2,"-")

         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.000000 -0.125000 -0.417126 -1.079445 -1.878111
[2,] 0.125000  0.000000 -0.292126 -0.954445 -1.753111
[3,] 0.417126  0.292126  0.000000 -0.662319 -1.460985
[4,] 1.079445  0.954445  0.662319  0.000000 -0.798666
[5,] 1.878111  1.753111  1.460985  0.798666  0.000000
```

If you want a long format of this matrix, you can use melt from `reshape`:

```
res <- outer(cADP2,cADP2,"-")
melt(res)
   X1 X2     value
1   1  1  0.000000
2   2  1  0.125000
3   3  1  0.417126
4   4  1  1.079445
5   5  1  1.878111
...
```

If you want only one side of the permutations (1-2 but not 2-1),you can use `upper.tri` or `lower.tri`. This will give you a vector:

```
res <- outer(cADP2,cADP2,"-")
res[upper.tri(res)]

-0.125000 -0.417126 -0.292126 -1.079445 -0.954445 -0.662319 -1.878111 -1.753111 -1.460985 -0.798666
```

Comment: Beat me to it! But do note, OP's initial object is not a numeric vector. Maybe need `as.vector(cADP2)`

Comment: Thank you so much @P Lapointe! Works a treat! You're right, @Parfait, but actually the data is a vector when first imported into R. I made it a matrix thinking it would be more helpful to work with.